# Docker access to future mounted volume

Tags: docker

I am currently wondering how I can access to an encrypted USB key without the `--privileged`. Let's say I have `/dev/sda1` a Luks encrypted key and `container` a running docker container. This key is opened via `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 encrypted_sda1 --key-file=key-file`. So now, I have `/dev/mapper/encrypted_sda1` accessible. Now, I exec `mount /dev/mapper/encrypted_sda1 /media/sda1` where `/media` is shared between my host and my container.

Now, from my host device, I can access to the content of my key via `/media/sda1`. But from my container (without `privileged`), I can't. I just have an empty directory called `sda1` in `/media`

The strange thing is if I run my container after mounting the USB key in `/media`, I can access to `/media/sda1` from the container. So I think it's because the volume is not correctly sync and there is something wrong with some rights.

I don't really understand why I can't access `/media/sda1` when I mount a USB key from the host when the container is running. Any lead?

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `--privileged`, I think you need to configure [bind propagation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation) on the `/media` mount. The default is `rprivate`, meaning that no mount points anywhere within the original or replica mount points propagate in either direction. If you use `rslave`, submounts (e.g., `/media/sda1`) of the original mount are visible in the replica.

```
docker container run --mount type=bind,source=/media,target=/media,bind-propagation=rslave …
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!